# How do i add a column to an existing text file in python?

Tags: python

I've created a text file in python, and now I want to add a 6th column with the same length of rows that repeats something like:

```
red
blue
yellow
green
red
blue
yellow
green
... to the end of the file
```

My original file looks like this

```
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00087.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00056.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00117.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00102.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00088.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00043.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00131.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491
```

and i want it to look like this

```
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00087.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491  red
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00056.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491  blue
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00117.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491  green
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00102.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491  yellow
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00088.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491  red
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00043.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491  green
rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00131.bin 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491 29.596454073622454 264.8326389532491  blue
```

Comment: Perhaps split it by '\n' character and insert text after each split

Comment: I didn't get the question. please give an example.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

The basic concept you are looking for is the modulo operator '%'.
https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

```
colors = ['red','blue','yellow','green']
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(f):
        color = colors[lineno % len(colors)]
        print(line.rstrip() + ' ' + color)
```

EDIT: Larger example that writes to a file instead of STDOUT:

```
colors = ['red','blue','yellow','green']
with open('file.txt') as ifh, open('out.txt', 'w') as ofh:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(ifh):
        line = line.rstrip()                 # remove newline
        color = colors[lineno % len(colors)] # choose color
        line += ' ' + color                  # append color
        ofh.write(line + '\n')               # write line
```

Comment: ok this is almost what im looking for... but instead of print i want to append file.txt with the colors column

Comment: line = line.rstrip() + ' ' + color

Comment: You will have to provide a little more context. Are you generating data in the loop of a python script, processing a file with a Python script, working on a Unix command line, something else? Can you post your code, or a representative excerpt?

Comment: file.txt is already created, i just want to either add a column that has the colors in it, or creating a whole new file is fine.  The way you have you example, when i try to do an f.write(line) it only writes the last files line.  I would like line to be written to a new file for every line in file.txt

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate the input file line by line and try to append appropriate color to it. For more details you can check the below snippet.

```py
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green']
with open('input.txt') as input_file, open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
        color = colors[i % len(colors)]
        new_line = '{} {}\n'.format(line.rstrip(), color)
        output_file.write(line)
```

Also there's another solution to being more functional. Let's check it!

```py
def get_new_line(t):
    l, c = t
    return '{} {}\n'.format(l.rstrip(), c)

colors = ['red','blue','yellow','green']
with open('input.txt') as input_file, open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    n, r = divmod(len(lines), len(colors))
    lines_color = colors * n + colors[:r]
    new_lines = list(map(get_new_line, zip(lines, lines_color)))
    output_file.writelines(new_lines)
```

Comment: if i wanted to add an additional column after the color column... what would i need to add to this code?

Comment: @ColleenB In 1st solution you can update `new_line` like this `new_line = '{} {} {}\n'.format(line.rstrip(), color, another_column)` and in the 2nd one you can update the returned value by `get_new_line` function like this `'{} {} {}\n'.format(l.rstrip(), c, another_column)`

Comment: Is there a way to add the column to the first column slot instead of the last?

Comment: @ColleenB you can update `new_line` to `new_line = '{} {}\n'.format(color, line.rstrip())` or if you want to add another column as the 1st column, you can do it like this `new_line = '{} {} {}\n'.format(another_column, line.rstrip(), color)`