# Need to make a new column in an existing txt file from another txt file

Tags: python, ascii

I have an existing txt file with 10 columns and around 5000 rows worth of data. The txt file (lets call it specfile) has headers that I use to access the data points using ascii.read(). What I need to do is add three new columns called 'UMINV', 'NUVMINJ', and 'VMINJ' as headers and then their subsequent data points to specfile. All of these columns are in the other file (colfile). I tried using a solution from: [How do i add a column to an existing text file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587469/how-do-i-add-a-column-to-an-existing-text-file-in-python) but the columns look like this:[image]

My code looks like

```py
specpath = '/home/user/GOGREEN_TEMP/SPECZ_MATCHED/compilation_SpARCS-0035_temp.dat'
colpathin = '/home/user/GOGREEN_TEMP/RESTFRAME_COLOURS/RESTFRAME_MASTER_SpARCS-0035_indivredshifts_temp.cat'

specfile = ascii.read(specpath)
colfile = ascii.read(colpathin)


UMINV = str(colfile['UMINV'])
with open('/home/user/GOGREEN_TEMP/RESTFRAME_COLOURS/RESTFRAME_MASTER_SpARCS-0035_indivredshifts_temp.cat') as ifh, open('/home/user/GOGREEN_TEMP/SPECZ_MATCHED/compilation_SpARCS-0035_temp2.dat', 'w') as ofh:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(ifh):
        line = line.rstrip()                 # remove newline
        color = UMINV[lineno % len(UMINV)] # choose color
        line += ' ' + color                  # append color
        ofh.write(line + '\n')               # write line
```

I get no error codes, but I get the incorrect appending result as shown in the picture. Any helo would be awesome!

Comment: For each row, you want to add all the 3 columns. Are both files of same length (# of rows)?

Comment: yes. each file has the same amount of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of structure the `ascii.read()` function returns. But try this, moving the `str()` transformation from the `UMINV` assignment line to the `color` line; also, adding a column header, and adjusting the `lineno` index on the `UMINV` column by one:

```
specpath = '/home/user/GOGREEN_TEMP/SPECZ_MATCHED/compilation_SpARCS-0035_temp.dat'
colpathin = '/home/user/GOGREEN_TEMP/RESTFRAME_COLOURS/RESTFRAME_MASTER_SpARCS-0035_indivredshifts_temp.cat'

specfile = ascii.read(specpath)
colfile = ascii.read(colpathin)

UMINV = colfile['UMINV']
with open('/home/user/GOGREEN_TEMP/RESTFRAME_COLOURS/RESTFRAME_MASTER_SpARCS-0035_indivredshifts_temp.cat') as ifh, open('/home/user/GOGREEN_TEMP/SPECZ_MATCHED/compilation_SpARCS-0035_temp2.dat', 'w') as ofh:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(ifh):
        line = line.rstrip()                       # remove newline
        color = str(UMINV[lineno-1 % len(UMINV)])  # choose color
        if lineno == 0:
            line += ' UMINV'                       # append header
        else:
            line += ' ' + color                    # append color
        ofh.write(line + '\n')                   # write line
```

Comment: What is the specific change proposed? Removing str from `UMINV = str(colfile['UMINV'])` ?

Comment: Your screenshot indicates that your entire added column was one character wide. That's what happens when you index on a string, here caused by writing `str(colfile['UMINV'])`, instead of leaving the `str()` off, which probably will yield one word or number for `UMINV[...]` to index against.

Comment: I added string because when I didn't I got an error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str". Other then that the code is working a lot better.

Comment: OK. I need to add the `str()` function in the `color` line. Got it. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That is starting to look a lot better! my issue now is that since I don't have a header, it is putting the first data entry as the header so everything is shifted down one. I would fix this by hand, but it screws everything up. Is there an easier way to do this? Here is a link of my issue https://imgur.com/a/zT3KWvv

Comment: Yes, there is. I will add it to the code in the answer